# Define read-only models in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, orm, model, sails.js, waterline

I am currently writing a Sails.js application with some CRUD operations. We have few models that have to be read-only; the stored data must left untouched in any case, no matter the used adapter.

This is what I have come up so far (still untested, but I think it should work):

```
module.exports = {
  autoPK: false,
  autoCreatedAt: false,
  autoUpdatedAt: false,
  attributes: {
    [...]
  },
  beforeValidate: (values, cb) => {
    cb(new Error('This is a read-only model'));
  },
  beforeDestroy: (criteria, cb) => {
    cb(new Error('This is a read-only model'));
  }
};
```

Based on [Lifecycle callbacks](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/lifecycle-callbacks), the `beforeValidate` and `beforeDestroy` functions are called before any "write" operation (create / update / destroy). Returning an error in these function will stop the operation.

Would you do this in a different manner? What do you think about this solution? Have you ever implemented such restrictions?

NB: For reasons, I can't set up the read/write configuration on our databases so that's not an alternative for me.

Comment: This looks the simplest to me. You can overwrite the default `Model.create`, `Model.update` etc, but that would be much more code. I do wonder if `beforeValidate` will pop up anywhere else you do want to use... associations with other models maybe? But from the docs, it does look like `beforeValidate` is the gatekeeper for update and creation. I would use this until you encounter any problems with it.

Comment: I'll go with this. If I happen to get some trouble I'll post my feedback here.